# Crashing issue due to memory management (using Core Data)

Tags: iphone, core-data, memory-management, nsoperation

I am using Core Data. From there i am retrieving 10000+ data

Using NSOperation, i am displaying huge data on UITableView.

but as i can see in XCode Instruments my memory usage continuously increasing

thats the reason, crashing activity is there in device not in simulator

Any one would like to comment on this ?

Comment: Getting Error: Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't retrieve 10000 objects at once.

Use the NSAutoreleasePool and flush the pool at some consistent interval (interval to be determined via testing).

Every N iterations:

1. save your context
2. reset your context
3. drain your pool

This will keep your memory usage down during import.

Comment: Marcus, I don't think it's a good idea to import so much data at once, even if he gets such import successfully running with your suggestion, he ends up with over 10000 objects in memory - all those just for a table-view is overkill. I'm also not sure from his description if that really is what he's doing - I understood that memory usage is increasing while he uses the app - that would suggest he's loading the data in tableView's datasource as required, which would be a correct approach, I guess.

Comment: If it is loading into a data source then he is not using an `NSFetchedResultsController`; hence my assumption that it was an import problem.

Comment: @Marcus: I am using NSFetchedResultsController.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
[fetchRequest setEntity:[me entity]];
// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
//TODO: Determine what batch size is appropriate, or should we batch at all
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50]; // tried with 0 as well
.......................

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] 
sectionNameKeyPath:[me sectionNameKeyPath] 
cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = me;

Comment: I am getting error -> Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib"

Comment: @Tariq: first; edit your post, code does not show up well in comments. Second, set a break point on objc_exception_throw so that you can capture the error earlier and see what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

Simulator has practically unlimited memory as it uses Mac's memory thus can even swap to hard drive. iDevice has on the other side very limited memory.

From your description it's not clear what you are doing wrong. It's up to you to analyse it, with Instruments you are already on a good way. Use Instruments's "Heapshot analysis" to find where your application is leaking memory. Recently bbum wrote a nice article about how to use it : http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ . There's also a nice video from WWDC by Apple's engineers about using Instruments worth watching : http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: I am getting error -> Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib"