# Crashing issue (using core data)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

i am getting a serious issue

Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
kill
quit

The Debugger has exited with status 0.(gdb)

Note: 
Problem occurs when i am fetching approx more than 5000+ data on tableview (using Core data)
If data is not huge then application doesnt crash.

Comment: This looks related to your earlier question: [Crashing issue due to memory management (using Core Data)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4131356/19679).  If you have additional information to supply, edit the original and don't repeat the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS** means: Exception Bad Access.

This is not a Core Data error. It is an exception from trying to access an object that has been released.

Turn on NSZombie, set a breakpoint on [objc_exception_throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163981/how-to-add-a-breakpoint-to-objc-exception-throw).  Then run your app again in the debugger and track down the over-release.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but it appears to be happening because of the amount of data you are loading. This sounds like a lot of data to be loading on an iPhone. Is there anyway you can reduce the volume? Perhaps you could create a table that contains summaries of your data. Or perhaps page load 20 or 30 records at a time rather than the full 5000.